How to find angle for area of triangle

I was able to figure out $|OP| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$  and that $P\hat{Q}O = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and it seem to be intuitive to me that $O\hat{P}Q = \frac{\pi}{2}$ but I'm not sure what's the "best"/easiest way to prove that.
I haven't used these pieces of information: "The plane $\mathit{\Pi}_3$ passes through $O$ and is normal to the line $BD$" and "$\mathit{\Pi}_3$ cuts $AD$ and $BD$ at the points $P$ and $Q$ respectively."
If I knew that $O\hat{P}Q = \frac{\pi}{2}$ then I could use trig ratios to find the other sides of the right-angle triangle and get the overall area.
It's probably something as simple as $OP$ is a normal vector for a plane $\mathit{\Pi}_1$ that passes through the origin. And since $Q$ exists on this plane, then $O\hat{P}Q = \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Where's the complete question?

https://media.cheggcdn.com/study/c8c/c8c68018-aff4-465f-9686-66725fc49226/image <-- the complete question but I don't think all of it is necessary for the question at hand?

If PI3 is normal to BD and passes through O, isn't Q necessarily the midpoint?

@Brandan: No. If the plane was parallel then yes.

The plane does not have to be parallel to ABCO for Q to be the midpoint.

In fact I believe this reasoning points to a miscalculation/assumption about the point P's coordinates.

Ofc the question is necessary

By similarity, $$\frac1{\sqrt2}=\frac{|\vec{OQ}|}{|\vec{BQ}|}=\frac{|\vec{QD}|}{|\vec{OQ}|}$$
which gives $$|\vec{OQ}|^2=Q_1^2+Q_2^2+Q_3^2=\frac45.$$ We also have $$\vec{OQ}\cdot\vec{BD}=Q_1+Q_2-Q_3=0.$$
Finally, $OQ$ bisects the angle between the planes $\Pi_1$ and $\Pi_2$ which is that between their normals. For example, we have $$\vec{OQ}\cdot\vec{AQ}=|\vec{OQ}||\vec{AQ}|\cos\left(\frac12\arccos\left(\frac{\vec{n_1}\cdot\vec{n_2}}{|\vec{n_1}||\vec{n_2}|}\right)\right).$$ Those are $3$ equations in $3$ unknowns. I am not sure though if they are enough.

I solved it...it is very simple

Find the lengths of $OP$, $OQ$ and $PQ$. Show by Pythagoras' theorem that $\angle OPQ=90°$.

Why don't you just state that $\angle OPQ=\pi/2$? I mean it's obvious that planes (ABD) and (OAD) are perpendicular, isn't it?

@ACB Usually when I think things are obvious I realize that I assumed to much. But I think with my method of just trig ratios and not finding Q, I could just state that plane AOD (containing P) is perpendicular to the $\mathit{\Pi}$ (containing Q) since the dot product of the normal vectors are zero: $<0,1,0> \cdot <1,0,1> = 0$ and so angle $O\hat{P}Q = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Find the equation of the plane $\Pi_3$. To find this, we have the direction ratio of the plane given in the question. Find the equation. Then find $P$ and $Q$. And prove what's required.
Don't solve this by vectors, solve it by using the concepts of three dimensional geometry.

In $\triangle ODB$ we have $OD=1, OB=\sqrt{2}, BD=\sqrt{3}$. Since $OQ \perp BD$, $\triangle OQD \sim \triangle OBD \implies \frac{OQ}{OD}=\frac{OB}{BD}, OQ=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$.
Now use right triangle $\triangle PQD$ to find $PQ$ and find the area of $\triangle OPQ$: $PD=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $DQ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \implies PQ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$.
Finally, we have sides for $\triangle OPQ$: $PQ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}, OP= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, OQ=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$Using Heron's formula:
$s=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}=\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{6}}, s-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{6}}, s-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{6}}, s-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{6}}$ $A_{\triangle OPQ}=\sqrt{\frac{6 \cdot 2}{16\cdot 36}}= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}$

I like your idea of similar triangles but the Area is supposed to be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}$

@Ally you are correct, I was incorrectly assuming that $\triangle OPQ$ is a right triangle. Let me update.
